# What is the simplest way to export a class from a static lib in my dll?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dllexport

I'm refactoring some common code from my dll to a static library.

**How can I define the class in the static library but still export it in the DLL?**

Here is an illustration.

```
#ifdef EXPORTING
#define EXPORT_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT_DLL __declspec(dllimport)


class EXPORT_DLL Example {
    double a,b,c;
  public:
    Example();
    ~Example();
    double Func1() const;
    void Func2(Example a);
};
```

I would need the following exports to still exist in the DLL

```
public: __cdecl Example::Example(void) __ptr64
public: __cdecl Example::~Example(void) __ptr64
public: double__cdecl Example::Func1(void) const __ptr64
public: __cdecl Example::Func2(class Example) __ptr64
```

I'm hoping there is a well-defined best practice. I'd rather not have to make my own .def exports.

After I remove this class from the project it will look like this in the static lib.

```
class Example {
    double a,b,c;
  public:
    Example();
    ~Example();
    double Func1() const;
    void Func2(Example a);
};
```

What code goes in the DLL?

Note: I am *not* creating a project that can be linked statically or dynamically. I am trying to forward classes from the static library project to DLL exports in a second wrapper project. This dll could potentially contain wrapper code if there is a way to do this with minimal plumbing.

Comment: @drescherjm I will try this solution. I was hoping to also cover the cases where I can't edit the source of the static library, but I didn't mention this in the question. (and yes, the order was a mistake. good catch)

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. I retract the duplicate

Comment: If you can't edit a static library leave it as a static library. Require the calling code to link to the static library to use it.

Comment: I tried defining EXPORT_DLL in the static lib, and this did help for some classes and functions but not others. The DLL doesn't seem to contain the code from the static lib unless they are inlined in the headers. So an exe would need to link against the example.lib and the exampleDLL.lib which is not what I was hoping for.